# USFX (XML); Extract verse by giving book, chapter and verse ID; Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to extract verses from the Bible which in my case is stored in the USFX ([Universal Scripture Format XML](https://ebible.org/usfx/)) format.

The USFX format is technically a valid XML but from the perspective of content not your usual hierarchical approach as it has to provide not only the simple "book, chapter, verse" structure but also has to satisfy requirements for poetry, comments and formatting in all languages of the world (a detailed write up of the 'why' is found [here](https://ebible.org/usfx/Bible-encoding.htm#challenges) by Michael Johnson.)

The structure of the XML looks like this (first 3 verses and first 2 chapters of the 1st book of the Spanish Bible (Reina Valera 1909 version):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<usfx xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="usfx.xsd">
    <languageCode>spa</languageCode>
    <book id="GEN">
        <id id="GEN"> Genesis</id>
        <h>Génesis</h>
        <toc level="1">Génesis</toc>
        <toc level="2">Génesis</toc>
        <p sfm="mt">Génesis</p>
        <c id="1"/>
        <p>
            <v id="1"/>
            <w s="H7225">EN el principio</w>
            <w s="H1254">crió</w>
            <w s="H0430">Dios</w>
            <w s="H8064">los cielos</w>
            <w s="H0776">y la tierra</w>.
            <ve/>
            <v id="2"/>
            <w s="H0776">Y la tierra</w>
            <w s="H1961">estaba</w>
            <w s="H8414">desordenada</w>
            <w s="H0922">y vacía</w>, <w s="H2822">y las tinieblas</w>
            <w s="H5921">estaban sobre</w>
            <w s="H6440">la haz</w>
            <w s="H8415">del abismo</w>, <w s="H7307">y el Espíritu</w>
            <w s="H0430">de Dios</w>
            <w s="H7363">se movía</w>
            <w s="H5921">sobre</w>
            <w s="H6440">la haz</w>
            <w s="H4325">de las aguas</w>.
            <ve/>
            <v id="3"/>
            <w s="H0559">Y dijo</w>
            <w s="H0430">Dios</w>: <w s="H1961">Sea</w>
            <w s="H0216">la luz</w>: <w s="H1961">y fué</w>
            <w s="H0216">la luz</w>.
            <ve/>
            .
            .  # 47 more verses
            .
        </p>
        <c id="2"/>
        <p>
            <v id="1"/>
            <w s="H3615">Y FUERON</w>
            <w s="H8064">acabados los cielos</w>
            <w s="H0776">y la tierra</w>, <w s="H3605">y todo</w>
            <w s="H6635">su ornamento</w>.
            <ve/>
            <v id="2"/>
            <w s="H3615">Y acabó</w>
            <w s="H0430">Dios</w>
            <w s="H3117">en el día</w>
            <w s="H7637">séptimo</w>
            <w s="H4399">su obra</w>
            <w s="H0834">que</w>
            <w s="H6213">hizo</w>, <w s="H7673">y reposó</w>
            <w s="H3117">el día</w>
            <w s="H7637">séptimo</w>
            <w s="H3605">de toda</w>
            <w s="H4399">su obra</w>
            <w s="H0834">que</w>
            <w s="H6213">había hecho</w>.
            <ve/>
            .
            .  # 23 more verses
            .
        </p>
        <c id="3"/>
        <p>...</p>
        <c id="4"/>
        <p>...</p>
        .
        .  # 45 more chapters
        .
        <c id="50"/>
        <p>...</p>
    </book>
    <book id="EXO">
        <id id="EXO"> Exodus</id>
        <h>Éxodo</h>
        <toc level="1">Éxodo</toc>
        <toc level="2">Éxodo</toc>
        <p sfm="mt">Éxodo</p>
        <c id="1"/>
        <p>
        .
        .
        .
    </book>
    .
    .   # 64 more books
    .
</usfx>
```

**Challenge**

As you can see, it is actually a very flat structure.

- Chapter IDs are only like labels but don't contain the actual content (verses)
- Verse IDs are also only like labels but do not contain the actual text of the verse
- Finally, the verse text is splitted into several sub segments (the w s=.. tags)

**Additional information**

I have searched quite a bit with google and also within SO but either I do not search the correct things or there is not much information on how to search and extract information from such a structure.

I tried to add the USFX tag to this question but it does not yet exist in SO and I have not enough rep to do that. Maybe someone with enough rep could add it?

**Question**

How can a verse be extracted from an USFX XML structure with Powershell by adressing it with book ID (or shortname), chapter ID and verse ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like using Xml Linq. Try code below.  I've been parsing text data for over 45 years.  This is how I usually parse complicated text

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$xmlFilename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'
$csvFilename = 'c:\temp\test.csv'
$xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($xmlFilename)

$books = $xDoc.Descendants('book')

$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($book in $books)
{
   $id = $book.Element('id').Value
   
   foreach($element in $book.Elements())
   {
      switch($element.Name.LocalName)
      {
         'id'  { $bookId = $element.Value } 
         'h'   { $h = $element.Value } 
         'toc' { $toc = $element.Attribute("level").Value } 
         'c'   { $chapter = $element.Attribute("id").Value }
         'p'   {
                  $attribute = $element.Attribute('sfm').Value
                  if($attribute -ne $null) { $sfm = $attribute } `
                  else {
                     $words = ''
                     foreach($pelement in $element.Elements())
                     {
                         switch($pelement.Name.LocalName)
                         {
                            'v' { 
                                   if($words.Length -ne 0)
                                   {
                                       $newRow = [pscustomObject]@{
                                          ID = $id
                                          'Book ID' = $bookId
                                          HEADER = $h
                                          TOC = $toc
                                          CHAPTER = $chapter
                                          SFM = $sfm
                                          VERSE = $verse
                                          Words = $words
                                       }
                                       $table.Add($newRow) | out-null
                                   }
                                   $verse = $pelement.Attribute('id').Value; $words = '' 
                                }
                            'w' { $word = $pelement.Value; $words = [string]::Join(' ', @($words, $word)) }
                         }
                     }
                     if($words.Length -ne 0)
                     {
                        $newRow = [pscustomObject]@{
                           ID = $id
                           'PARA ID' = $paraId
                           'Book ID' = $bookId
                           HEADER = $h
                           TOC = $toc
                           CHAPTER = $chapter
                           SFM = $sfm
                           VERSE = $verse
                           Words = $words
                        }
                        $table.Add($newRow) | out-null
                     }
                  }
               } 
      }  
   }
}
$table | Export-CSV -Path $csvFilename -NoTypeInformation
$table
```

Comment: This one works great. Just a small optimization for someone coming to this answer: The "using" directive is not usable within Powershell (looks like it comes from C#) and should read in Powershell: "add-type -AssemblyName System.Xml.Linq". Also Excel seems to have some problems with the exported Umlauts. I will play around with the encoding of the export (probably using UTF8BOM or so). Thx for this solution.

Comment: @JohnRanger : I needed the using statement with PS 5.  I recently upgraded to PS 7.  Not sure if it is still needed. My code run without any modifications.  The using statement must be at the top of the module.

Comment: I think the Unlauts issue is a Font Issue.

Comment: @JohnRanger: `using namespace System.Xml.Linq` _should_ work in PS 7+, but is currently broken (see [GitHub issue #11856](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11856)). However, it isn't actually needed there, because the assembly is preloaded, unlike in Windows PowerShell. `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Xml.Linq` works in _both_ editions. Re umlauts: when jdweng says "font", he means _character encoding_. PS 7+ produces UTF-8 files _without BOM_ by default; conceivably, Excel needs a BOM to recognize the encoding, so try adding `-Encoding utf8bom` to the `Export-Csv` call.

Comment: I do not understand what is going on.  I have PS 7 installed on Win 11 and without the using statement I get an error.

Comment: For the "using" issue, just use the good - old add-type. Regarding the "font" issue, this is an encoding issue and if you export it from Powershell with "-encoding UTF8BOM" then it works flawlessly within Excel. Encoding UTF8BOM only exists within Powershell 7.

Comment: The Powershell extension of VS Code complains when using the "using" directive - so I used the old way with add-type where it does not complain.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing this repeatedly then my usual recommendation is to start by transforming the structure to something in which the hierarchy is explicit, which is typically done in XSLT 2.0+ using constructs such as `xsl:for-each-group group-starting-with="c"/>` to get the contents of one chapter. Searching for a particular verse then involves a straightforward XPath expression.

If you want to do it without a preliminary transformation, then the following XQuery 3.1 expression does the job:

```
declare variable $bookId external := "GEN";
declare variable $chapterId external := "1";
declare variable $verseId external := "2";

let $book := //book[@id=$bookId]
for tumbling window $c in $book/* start $c-init when $c-init[self::c]
where $c-init/@id = $chapterId
for tumbling window $v in $c/self::p/* start $v-init when $v-init[self::v]
where $v-init/@id = $verseId
return <verse>{string-join($v/self::w, ' ')}</verse>
```

With the parameter values shown as defaults, the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><verse>Y la tierra estaba desordenada y vacía y las tinieblas estaban sobre la haz del abismo y el Espíritu de Dios se movía sobre la haz de las aguas</verse>
```

If you want an XQuery 3.1 processor that you can invoke from Powershell, Saxon would be a candidate.

It's not really a practical suggestion at the moment but when XPath 4.0 stabilises, you should be able to do something like this:

```
let $book := //book[@id=$bookId]
let $chap := subsequence($book/*, 
                         starting-when := fn{self::c/@id = $chapterId}
                         ending-when := fn{boolean(self::p)})
let $verse := subsequence($chap/p,
                         starting-when := fn{self::v/@id = $verseId}
                         ending-when := fn{boolean(self::ve)})
return string-join($verse/w, ' ')
```

Comment: I have to admit that I don't understand this approach. It is surely not plain Powershell code. You are writing of an external xquery processor. I will look into it when I find time for it. Thanks anyway for taking time to answer my question.

Comment: I think this task is way beyond what Powershell can do on its own. Powershell is powerful, but it's primarily intended as a shell for invoking other more specialised tools.

Comment: If you look at the answer by jdweng, it is perfectly possible to do it with Powershell :-) - As Powershell allows to use the full .net framework. I didn't know about the System.Xml.Linq and its great selection capabilities..

Comment: Yes, I had forgotten quite how much can be achieved with XPath 1.0 - it's incredibly contorted and inefficient, really feels like knocking in nails with a screwdriver, but if Powershell is your only tool then I concede that it can be made to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using XPath (for version 1.0).

```
function Get-Verse {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName='BibleShortName', Position=0)]
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName='BibleId', Position=0)]
    [string]$BibleXml,
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName='BibleId')]
    [string]$BibleId,
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName='BibleShortName')]
    [string]$BibleShortName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName='BibleShortName')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName='BibleId')]
    [string]$Chapter,
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName='BibleShortName')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName='BibleId')]
    [string]$Verse
  )
  $xpath = ''
  if( $BibleId ) {
    $xpath = @"
[@id="${BibleId}"]
  /
"@
  } else {
    $xpath = @"
`n  /id[contains(.,"${BibleShortName}")]
    /following-sibling::
"@
  }
  $xpath = @"
//book${xpath}c[@id="${Chapter}"]
      /following-sibling::p[1]
        /v[@id="${Verse}"]
          /following-sibling::ve[1]
            /preceding-sibling::node()[preceding-sibling::v[@id="${Verse}"] and
                                       ( local-name()="w" or
                                         .=preceding-sibling::w[1]
                                             /following-sibling::text()[1] )]
"@
  Write-Verbose -Message "`n${xpath}"
  $nn = Select-Xml -Path $BibleXml -XPath $xpath
  -join @( for( $i = 0; $i -lt $nn.Length; $i++ ) {
             $n = $nn[$i].Node
             if( $n.localname -in '#whitespace', '#text' ) { $n.Value }
             elseif( $n.localname -eq 'w' ) { $n.'#text' }
           } )
}
```

Usage example. The `spa-rv1909.usfx.xml` file was uploaded from [here](https://github.com/seven1m/open-bibles/blob/a029269c55520c8b535845e1f7f5741ccbaf6cc8/spa-rv1909.usfx.xml).

```
Get-Verse -BibleXml ${env:USERPROFILE}\Downloads\spa-rv1909.usfx.xml -BibleId GEN -Chapter 12 -Verse 8
```

Result:

```
Y pasóse de allí á un monte al oriente de Bethel, y tendió su tienda, teniendo á Bethel al occidente y Hai al oriente: y edificó allí altar á Jehová, é i
nvocó el nombre de Jehová.
```